# How can I connect a site on Namecheap to a domain on Wix?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, domain-registrar, nameserver, cname

I bought a domain and hosted a site with Wix. Recently, I needed a custom site for which I bought a hosting from Namecheap and uploaded the site files to namecheap server. But Wix wont allow me to edit the nameservers of the domain i have from them. 
So I added the A record and modified the CNAME record as shown in the image below. It's been 2 hours. but the domain still says **bad gateway** when visited. How do I solve this?

[image]

Comment: Where did you get the 216.87... IP address?  Is that the IP of the hosting at Namecheap? Have you added the domain to your Namecheap account so that Namecheap knows which account's files should be served for that domain name?  Have you used any DNS lookup tools to verify that the domain is now pointing to the IP address you specified?

Comment: DSN propagation can sometimes take up to 24h so when you say: 'It's been 2 hours...' it is possible that the propagation isn't complete yet.